# Python Django Rest Framework authentication

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I am attempting to authenticate a **GUID** that is being passed in the url via the web API interface. However I am not managing to pass **GUID** to my **Authenticate** class.

*Note: by authenticating I mean making sure it is a valid GUID*

My **urls.py**:

```
 url(r'^customer_address/(?P<guid>[a-z0-9-]+)/(?P<address_id>[a-z0-9-]+)/$',
    views.CustomerAddressView.as_view()),
```

My **views.py**:

```
class CustomerAddressView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    lookup_field = "address_id"       
    queryset = CustomerAddress.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerAddressSerializer
```

My **settings.py**:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
            'customer.authenticate.Authenticate',
        ),
         'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
         )
}
```

**Authenticate** class in my customer app looks like this:

```
class Authenticate(authentication.BaseAuthentication) :
    def authenticate(self, request):

        request = request._request                               
        guid = getattr(request, 'guid', None)


        my_logger.debug(guid)


        if not guid:
            my_logger.debug('There is no guid!')
            return None


        try:
            user = Customer.objects.get(guid=guid,brand=1)
        except Customer.DoesNotExist:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('No such user')

        return None
```

And the request looks like this:

[image]

Problem: 
I like to retrieve a **GUID** in class Authenticate and make sure it is valid. At the moment I keep getting the error you see in the screenshot and my logs read: 'There is no guid!'

How can I pass guid from request to the Authenticate class?

Thanks

Comment: Check if you have access to `kwargs` in self. Do `guid = self.kwargs.get('guid', None)`

Comment: I have checked, you don't have the `kwargs` of the DRF view in `authenticate()`. I have updated my ans. Another solution is to pass the `kwargs` of the view to `authenticate()` when it is called.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
class Authenticate(authentication.BaseAuthentication) :
    def authenticate(self, request):

        request = request._request        

        # This is a bit hacky way to get value of guid                        
        guid = request.path.split('/')[-3]

        my_logger.debug(guid)

        if not guid:
            my_logger.debug('There is no guid!')
        return None

        try:
            user = Customer.objects.get(guid=guid,brand=1)
        except Customer.DoesNotExist:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('No such user')

    return None
```

This is a bit hacky since i am trying to access `guid` by splitting `request.path` about `'/'` and access the third-last index of the list obtained after splitting.

I have checked, `self` has no access to the `kwargs` which we normally get in DRF views, so we can't access `kwargs` here.

Another solution would be to pass `kwargs` in the DRF view explicitly when `authenticate()` is called by overriding the authentication process of DRF.